# formData no envia documento en formulario

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estoy enviando un formulario por **AJAX** en su mayoría tiene campos tipo texto excepto un **input file** al enviarlo con un formdata llegan todos los datos excepto el dato del **input file** estoy utilizando php para resibir los datos y guardar el documento en una carpeta de mi computador eh investigado pero no encuentro como resolverlo.
dejo fragmento de código:

**HTML**
con un poco del formulario que estoy usando no estoy usando un form para enviarlo solo obtengo todos los datos con un **val()** de js

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field">
     <div class="btn">
       <span>Subir PDF CV</span>
       <input type="file" id="txt_pdf_cv" name="txt_pdf_cv">
     </div>
     <div class="file-path-wrapper">
       <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" name="button" id="btn_registrar" class="btn btn_registrar" onclick="acordeon_tres();enviarForm()">REGISTRAR</button>
</div>
```

***JS***
en el Js estoy creando un objeto **formData** para recibir y enviar mis datos estoy utilizando una funcion Files para enviar el documento

```
function enviarForm(){
        var frmData = new FormData();
        frmData.append("txt_pdf_cv",$("#txt_pdf_cv")[0].files[0]);
        frmData.append("txt_nombre",$("#txt_nombre").val());
        frmData.append("enviar","correcto");
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              data:frmData,
              cache: false,
              url: "includes/ajax/formulario_usuario.php",
              success: function(datos) {
                  $(".formulario_usuario").html(datos).show();
              },
              beforeSend: function() {
                  document.getElementById("formulario").style.opacity = "0.5";
                  document.getElementById("btn_registrar").disabled = true;
              },
              complete: function() {
                  document.getElementById("formulario").style.opacity = "1";
                  document.getElementById("btn_registrar").disabled = false;
              }
          });
      }
```

***php***
estoy recibiendo los datos para posteriormente guardar en la carpeta y guardar en BDD solo puse el codigo para el copiado del archivo

```
    <?php if($_POST["enviar"] == "correcto"){
   $txt_nombre = $_POST["txt_nombre"];

   $txt_pdf_cv = $_POST["txt_pdf_cv"];
   if ($txt_pdf_cv != '') {
     echo "hola";
     function gen_chars_no_dup($long = 25) {
        $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i != $long) {
            $rand = mt_rand() % strlen($chars);
            $tmp = $chars[$rand];
            $pass = $pass . $tmp;
            $chars = str_replace($tmp, "", $chars);
            $i++;
        }
        return strrev($pass);
     }
      $file_temp_name = gen_chars_no_dup();
      $nombre = $_FILES['txt_pdf_cv']['name'];
      $path = $_FILES['txt_pdf_cv']['name'];
      $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $nombrer = strtolower($file_temp_name) ;
      $cd=$_FILES['txt_pdf_cv']['tmp_name'];
      $ruta = "pdf/". $nombrer.'.'.$ext;
      $destino = "pdf/".$nombrer.'.'.$ext;
      $guardar = $nombrer.'.'.$ext;;
      $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["txt_pdf_cv"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en tu archivo PHP estas recibiendo el archivo por $_POST debes usar la variable global $_FILES

```
$archivo = $_FILES['txt_pdf_cv'];
```

Para comprobar si esta vácio puedes usar

```
if(empty($archivo)){}
```

o directamente

```
if(empty($_FILES['txt_pdf_cv']))
```

Después yo haría la petición **AJAX** de esta forma

```
function enviarForm(){
    var archivo = document.getElementById('txt_pdf_cv').files[0],
        nombre_archivo = document.getElementById('nombre-archivo').value;

    var frmData = new FormData();

    frmData.append("txt_pdf_cv",archivo);
    frmData.append("nombre-archivo",nombre_archivo);      

      $.ajax({
          url: "archivo_procesar.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: frmData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,             
          success: function(datos) {
              // más codigo
          }
      });
  }
```